# What happens if <base href...> is set with a double slash?

Tags: html, html-head

I like to understand how to use a `<base href="" />` value for my web crawler, so I tested several combinations with major browsers and finally found something with double slashes I don't understand.

If you don't like to read everything jump to the test results of **D** and **E**. Demonstration of all tests:
http://gutt.it/basehref.php

Step by step my test results on calling `http://example.com/images.html`:

**A - Multiple base href**

```
<html>
<head>
<base target="_blank" />
<base href="http://example.com/images/" />
<base href="http://example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
<img src="image.jpg">
<img src="./image.jpg">
<img src="images/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="../image.jpg"> not found
</body>
</html>
```

*Conclusion*

- only the first `<base>` with `href` counts
- a source starting with `/` targets the root
- `../` goes one folder up

**B - Without trailing slash**

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/images" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
<img src="image.jpg"> not found
<img src="./image.jpg"> not found
<img src="images/image.jpg">
<img src="/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="../image.jpg"> not found
</body>
</html>
```

*Conclusion*

- `<base href>` ignores everything after the last slash so `http://example.com/images` becomes `http://example.com/`

**C - How it should be**

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
<img src="image.jpg"> not found
<img src="./image.jpg"> not found
<img src="images/image.jpg">
<img src="/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="../image.jpg"> not found
</body>
</html>
```

*Conclusion*

- Same result as in **Test B** as expected

**D - Double Slash**

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/images//" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
<img src="image.jpg">
<img src="./image.jpg">
<img src="images/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="../image.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

**E - Double Slash with whitespace**

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/images/ /" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
<img src="image.jpg"> not found
<img src="./image.jpg"> not found
<img src="images/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="/image.jpg"> not found
<img src="../image.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Both are not "valid" URLs, but real results of my web crawler. Please explain what happend in **D** and **E** that `../image.jpg` could be found and why causes the whitespace a difference?

Only for your interest:

- `<base href="http://example.com//" />` is the same as **Test C**
- `<base href="http://example.com/ /" />` is completely different. Only `../image.jpg` is found
- `<base href="a/" />` finds only `/images/image.jpg`

Comment: I mean you can simply try that. Why you didn't it?

Comment: @panther Of course I did. You did not read the description. Please remove your downvote and close request.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161264/2126792. By definition you should only user single slashes... double slashes will be handled differently depending on server setup.

Comment: @pschueller If multiple slashes would act as one slash (as described in your link) the **Test D** and **E** would result the same as **A**.

Comment: @pschueller I know that my example is not "valid", but this is a real life example through my crawler so I wanted to know how to use base href in this special cases. So finally I don't have influence of the html source.

Comment: _“a source starting with / targets the root (ignores `<base>`)”_ – it doesn’t _“ignore”_ it – a leading slash simply refers to the root, no matter what – by _definition_. This has nothing to do with whether a base is given or not.

Comment: Now I've added a demo page to the description as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) is explained in the HTML spec:

> The [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) element allows authors to specify the [document base
>   URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#document-base-url) for the purposes of [resolving relative URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url).

As shown in your test A, if there are multiple `base` with `href`, the [document base URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#document-base-url) will be the first one.

[Resolving relative URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url) is done this way:

> Apply the [URL parser](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#url-parser-0) to *url*, with *base* as the base URL, with *encoding* as the encoding.

The [URL parsing](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-parsing) algorithm is defined in the URL spec.

It's too complex to be explained here in detail. But basically, this is what happens:

- A relative URL starting with `/` is calculated with respect to base URL's host.
- Otherwise, the relative URL is calculated with respect to base URL's last directory.
- Be aware that if the base path doesn't end with `/`, the last part will be a file, not a directory.
- `./` is the current directory
- `../` goes one directory up

<sup>(Probably, "directory" and "file" are not the proper terminology in URLs)</sup>

Some examples:

- `http://example.com/images/a/./` is `http://example.com/images/a/`
- `http://example.com/images/a/../` is `http://example.com/images/`
- `http://example.com/images//./` is `http://example.com/images//`
- `http://example.com/images//../` is `http://example.com/images/`
- `http://example.com/images/./` is `http://example.com/images/`
- `http://example.com/images/../` is `http://example.com/`

Note that, in most cases, `//` will be like `/`. As [said by @poncha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161264/1529630),

> Unless you're using some kind of URL rewriting (in which case the
>   rewriting rules may be affected by the number of slashes), the uri
>   maps to a path on disk, but in (most?) modern operating systems
>   (Linux/Unix, Windows), multiple path separators in a row do not have
>   any special meaning, so /path/to/foo and /path//to////foo would
>   eventually map to the same file.

However, in general `/ /` won't become `//`.

You can use the following snippet to resolve your list of relative URLs to absolute ones:

```js
var bases = [
  "http://example.com/images/",
  "http://example.com/images",
  "http://example.com/",
  "http://example.com/images//",
  "http://example.com/images/ /"
];
var urls = [
  "/images/image.jpg",
  "image.jpg",
  "./image.jpg",
  "images/image.jpg",
  "/image.jpg",
  "../image.jpg"
];
function newEl(type, contents) {
  var el = document.createElement(type);
  if(!contents) return el;
  if(!(contents instanceof Array))
    contents = [contents];
  for(var i=0; i<contents.length; ++i)
    if(typeof contents[i] == 'string')
      el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contents[i]))
    else if(typeof contents[i] == 'object') // contents[i] instanceof Node
      el.appendChild(contents[i])
  return el;
}
function emoticon(str) {
  return {
    'http://example.com/images/image.jpg': 'good',
    'http://example.com/images//image.jpg': 'neutral'
  }[str] || 'bad';
}
var base = document.createElement('base'),
    a = document.createElement('a'),
    output = document.createElement('ul'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.insertBefore(base, head.firstChild);
for(var i=0; i<bases.length; ++i) {
  base.href = bases[i];
  var test = newEl('li', [
    'Test ' + (i+1) + ': ',
    newEl('span', bases[i])
  ]);
  test.className = 'test';
  var testItems = newEl('ul');
  testItems.className = 'test-items';
  for(var j=0; j<urls.length; ++j) {
    a.href = urls[j];
    var absURL = a.cloneNode(false).href;
      /* Stupid old IE requires cloning
         https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437713/1529630 */
    var testItem = newEl('li', [
      newEl('span', urls[j]),
      ' → ',
      newEl('span', absURL)
    ]);
    testItem.className = 'test-item ' + emoticon(absURL);
    testItems.appendChild(testItem);
  }
  test.appendChild(testItems);
  output.appendChild(test);
}
document.body.appendChild(output);
```

```css
span {
  background: #eef;
}
.test-items {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: .13em;
  padding-left: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: .3em;
}
.test-item {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.test-item > span {
  display: table-cell;
}
.test-item:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: .4em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.1em;
  top: 0;
}
.good:before {
  content: ':)';
  background: #0f0;
}
.neutral:before {
  content: ':|';
  background: #ff0;
}
.bad:before {
  content: ':(';
  background: #f00;
}
```

You can also play with this snippet:

```js
var resolveURL = (function() {
  var base = document.createElement('base'),
      a = document.createElement('a'),
      head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  return function(url, baseurl) {
    if(base) {
      base.href = baseurl;
      head.insertBefore(base, head.firstChild);
    }
    a.href = url;
    var abs = a.cloneNode(false).href;
    /* Stupid old IE requires cloning
       https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437713/1529630 */
    if(base)
      head.removeChild(base);
    return abs;
  };
})();
var base = document.getElementById('base'),
    url = document.getElementById('url'),
    abs = document.getElementById('absolute');
base.onpropertychange = url.onpropertychange = function() {
  if (event.propertyName == "value")
    update()
};
(base.oninput = url.oninput = update)();
function update() {
  abs.value = resolveURL(url.value, base.value);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Base url:
  <input id="base" value="http://example.com/images//foo////bar/baz"
         placeholder="Enter your base url here" />
</label>
<label>
  URL to be resolved:
  <input id="url" value="./a/b/../c"
         placeholder="Enter your URL here">
</label>
<label>
  Resulting url:
  <input id="absolute" readonly>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what happens. In Test D `//` is one level deeper then `images/` so `../` targets `images/`. But if a target contains `//` as it is with `./image.jpg` the second one is ignored. To clear things up I will edit your answer a little bit. Feel free to use it.