# .htaccess pretty url formatting is not stripping slashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url

I'm using this line in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pages=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

It works fine, but I can place slashes before the content. For example: `/contact` is same as `/////contact`

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161177/url-with-multiple-forward-slashes-does-it-break-anything

Comment: thanks, I thought I messed up something